# Getting GNU Emacs Windows to run my ~/.bash_profile when creating a Cygwin M-x shell subprocess

Tags: emacs, cygwin, .bash-profile

I use GNU Emacs on Windows and Cygwin for the shell that I do all my work in.  The ~/.profile used by Cygwin is ~/.bash_profile.  If I start a Cygwin shell by running C:\cygwin\Cygwin.bat, it starts up and executes ~/.bash_profile fine.

I set up Cygwin in GNU Emacs on Windows by putting the following in my ~/.emacs, as prescribed:

```
;; Set up Cygwin
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Program Files/emacs-site-lisp/cygwin")
(require 'setup-cygwin)
```

C:\Program Files\emacs-site-lisp is where I put my site-wide lisp (obviously).

When I run M-x shell, a Cygwin bash subprocess is created in a buffer named *shell*.  Perfect.  However, my ~/.bash_profile is not executed.

How do I make the ~/.bash_profile take effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer I can give is a link that explains the differences between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`: http://joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

There's a whole lot of history there and some of it has to do with The Old Days when we'd dial in to systems with slow modems and we wanted a shell up and running fast. So we'd want to "login" with an environment that was quick to setup and then spawn "sub-shells" that were fully configured because that was faster to do from an already logged in shell.

In your case your inital shell is being started as a login shell (check `cygwin.bat` -- it's calling `bash` with `--login`). But the emacs sub-shell is not being started as a login shell. So only your `.bashrc` file is being loaded.

These days I think most people just keep it all in .bashrc and have .bash_profile load that instead:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

But you need to be careful that you don't repeatedly append to variables like `PATH` if you take this approach. Otherwise, every sub-shell ends up with duplicate entries on the `PATH` and you can get really long and unruly variables that need to be searched and things slow down.

Comment: The distinction between `.profile` and `.bashrc` has nothing to do with efficiency: they're for different purposes. `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` is for stuff to do on login, such as setting environment variables and running programs that you want to start once per session. `~/.bashrc` is for configuring the interactive shell (aliases, key bindings, etc). The reason why you'd want to source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.bash_profile` is a design bug in bash: it doesn't read `~/.bashrc` in a login shell, even if that login shell is interactive.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it - and it works:

```
(setq explicit-bash-args '("--login" "--init-file" "c:/home/cbalz/.bash_profile" "-i"))
```

One would think that 'bash.exe' would run '.bash_profile' without the explicit init file, since this is a login shell ('--login') and 'bash.exe' does properly find and execute '.bashrc'.  This is not the case however.  Since '.bash_profile' sources '.bashrc', the solution is to just run '.bash_profile'.

I think Cygwin should run a Windows service to manage the environment variables, so that shells could inherit properly.